# Cron expression for scheduling task in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, cron

I want to schedule a job in spring boot using @Scheduled annotation, that runs at the following interval 00:01, 01:01, 02:01, 03:01 and so on in UTC time how can that be done ?

What will be the correct cron expression for it and importantly it should follow UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer：

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 1 0,1,2,3 * * ? ",zone = "UTC")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).